# ClassCast Exception in java, cannot cast to Ljava.lang.Integer

Tags: java

I am trying to use java generics-

```
 public T[] toArray()
   {


      T[] result = (T[])new Object[numberOfEntries]; 

       // some code here to fill the resultarray



     return result;
   } // end toArray
```

Now in my main funciton, this is what I am doing-

```
        A<Integer> obj= new A<Integer> ();

        obj.add(1); //add method not shown here as it is not relevant to question
        obj.add(2);
        obj.add(3);
        obj.add(4);


        Integer arr[] = (Integer[]) obj.toArray();
```

I get the following error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at tester.main(tester.java:14)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to type erasure, the `toArray()` method will return an array of type `Object[]`, not `Integer[]`, and it is not possible to cast `Object[]` to `Integer[]`.

If you want to return an `Integer` array at runtime from your generic class, you can try passing in the actual class type as a parameter to the `toArray()` method:

```
public T[] toArray(Class<T> c, int size) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, s);
    return result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
A<Integer> obj= new A<Integer> ();

obj.add(1);
obj.add(2);
obj.add(3);
obj.add(4);

Integer[] arr = obj.toArray(Integer.class, obj.size());
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to cast an object of type `Object[]` to `Integer[]`. These are incompatible types so the JVM throws a `ClassCastException`. You need to provide some runtime type information to `toArray`, for example like this:

```
public T[] toArray(Class<T> clazz)
{
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  T[] result = (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, numberOfEntries);
  // some code here to fill the resultarray
  return result;
}

...

// and use it like this:
Integer arr[] = obj.toArray(Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in code T[] result = (T[])new Object[numberOfEntries];
You need to replace it with T[] result = (T[])new T[numberOfEntries];

Comment: I suppose you cannot say `new T[]` - have you tried that?

Comment: Generic T can not be instantiated directly!

Answer (score 0):

`Object[]` cannot cast to `Integer[]` directly. Use below code to move elements one by one:

```
    Object[] arr = new Object[SIZE];
    Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[arr.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(Object a:arr){
        arr1[i++] = (Integer)a;
    }
```